# jqGrid does not bind json rows.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid by Trirand. The grid headers, rows, paging is displayed correctly but the data rows are not populated. I have gone through many posts and tried many solutions, but it simply won't work. I'm sure there some thing very simple that is missing but I am unable to figure it out.

I am getting the following response from my ASP.NET MVC Controller:

> {    "total":1, "page":1, "records":2,    "rows":     [
>              { "Id":"1", "StudentName":"Student1" },
>              { "Id":"2", "StudentName":"Student2" }    ] }

And the jqGrid code is as follows:

> ```
> $(function () {
>
> $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
>
>     url: '/Home/GetStudentsLists',
>     dataType: "json",
>     mtype: 'GET',
>     colNames: ['Id', 'StudentName'],
>     colModel: [
>         { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 60 },
>         { name: 'StudentName', index: 'StudentName', width: 60 }
>     ],        
>     rowNum: 9999,
>     sortname: 'Id',
>     loadonce: true,
>     rowList: [10, 20, 30],
>     pager: '#jqpager',
>     viewrecords: true,
>     sortorder: "desc",
>     caption: "Students Details",
>     height: 100,
>     autowidth: true        
> }) });
> ```

and the Layout page that contains the script tags looks like following:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    ...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Custom/jQGridStudents.js"></script>
</body>
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use (or can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? If you use not "free jqGrid" then you have to fix `dataType: "json"` to `datatype: "json"`. It should be your main problem. Other recommendation in your code would depend on the version and fork of jqGrid, which you use.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm using jquery.jqGrid by Trirand, version 4.4.4, and jquery version 3.1.1 available on nuget, and I can use any of these grids you have mentioned. Secondly, I think you have written dataType: "json" twice in your comment.  See text above [dataType: "json" to dataType: "json"].

Comment: JavaScript is **case sensitive** and `datatype` is **not the same** as `dataType` (with capical `T`). The version 4.4.4 is 4.5 years old and it's dead since a long time. If you use NuGet, then I recommend you uninstall old packge and to use [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/). Alternatively I recommend you to consider to load free jqGrid from CDN. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#the_first_grid_code).

Comment: Thank you Oleg! It did worked.

Answer (score 0):

So Oleg here helped me find the problem. Thanks for your help Oleg.

The problem was due to a simple typo where I wrote dataType instead of datatyppe. Everything started working as soon as I changed dataType to datatype.

Secondly, the jqgrid I'm using was too old, so I am gonna go with the latest one as mentioned above in comments by Oleg.